# JavaScript: Effects of multiple AJAX in modern browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello I am new to programming. I know that you can make multiple ajax calls but I wanted to know what is the limit for AJAX call. Also what are the side effect of making multiple Ajax calls? Also what is there any browser set rule for that?

Comment: There is no limit to the number of AJAX calls that you can make. Side effect: `harder to debug since its all asynchronous`. If you are talking about concurrent AJAX calls to the same domain then you can make upto 6 AJAX calls.

Comment: LImit is not Ajax calls, but how many HTTP Requests you can have active at one time.

Comment: While there is no limit, [your browser might not process all HTTP requests at the same time.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

Comment: @vinayakj I know it might sound similar. Also that question was asked 7 years ago. Another thing is that I am trying to know is that what problem do you face once you make multiple request.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the comment. How do the browser handle the request it then?

Comment: [There are tons of answers on SO about it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)